# Error in matlab stratified cross validation partitioning "CVPARTITION can have at most one optional argument"

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I am trying to perform stratified cross validation as the data is highly imbalanced. The output labels of the data are in the matrix `predictionMatrix`. It is a 832*1 dimensional matrix with values 0/1. For cross validation, I am using the function `cvpartition`, but it is generating the error:

```
CVPARTITION can have at most one optional argument
```

The code is:

```matlab
c = cvpartition(predictionMatrix,'KFold',5,'Stratify',true);
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can reproduce your error and help in solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using an older version of MATLAB. For example, in MATLAB release R2016a, the `cvpartition` command takes only one pair of optional arguments as in

```
c = cvpartition(predictionMatrix,'KFold',5)
```

and the option `...'Stratify',true` is not available at all. So you would get the same error as yours:

```
I = randi(100,832,1);
predictionMatrix = (I>50);
c = cvpartition(predictionMatrix,'KFold',5,'Stratify',true);

  Error using cvpartition (line 130)
  CVPARTITION can have at most one optional argument
```

However, in MATLAB release R2018a and beyond, the same code works just fine:

```
I = randi(100,832,1);
predictionMatrix = (I>50);
c = cvpartition(predictionMatrix,'KFold',5,'Stratify',true)

c = 

K-fold cross validation partition
   NumObservations: 832
       NumTestSets: 5
         TrainSize: 666  665  665  666  666
          TestSize: 166  167  167  166  166
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, when I am using stratified cross validation, I get the warning on execution: "One or more folds do not contain points from all the groups". This may be due to the highly imbalanced nature of my data. How can I perform stratified cross validation with replacement?